# Javascript - How to get all elements and do same thing on each of them

Tags: javascript, parent, element

I want to get all DIVs in DIV(id = room) and do the same javascript code on each one.

I think it should look like this

*Get element by id room -> Get all divs inside -> do something on them(change each class to "grass")*

or by using a loop.

How to do that?

**Please don't use jQuery.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modern browsers (IE9+):

```
var divs = document.querySelectorAll('#room div');

[].forEach.call(divs, function(div){
  div.className = 'green';
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var a = document.getElementById("room").getElementsByTagName("div");

for(i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
{
    a[i].className = "grass";
}
```

Comment: This misses the *Get all divs inside* step.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to get **all** divs inside, or just direct children?

This one traverses direct children. If you want to go through all internal nodes, you need to recurse it.

```
function grassify(nodeId) {

  var node = document.getElementById(nodeId);
  for(var i in node.childNodes) {
    // Do things with node.childNodes[i], for example:
    node.childNodes[i].className = 'grass';
  }
}
```

Then just:

```
grassify('room');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function myFunction()
{
var a=document.getElementById('room').childNodes;
for (i=0; i<a.length; i++)
  {
  a[i].className="grass";
  };
}
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HZB6c/)

Answer (score 1):

```
var room=document.getElementByID("#room");
   var divs=room.getElementsByTagName("div");
   for(var i=0;i<divs.length;i++){
      doSomething(divs[i]);
}
```

Use [getElementByID](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementById) and [getElementsByTagName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.getElementsByTagName)

Answer (score 1):

Use getElementsByTagName

First get a reference to the container element, then use getElementsByTagName for the type of element you want.

See http://jsfiddle.net/aQtTx/

JS:

```
var targetDiv = document.getElementById("div1");
var nestedDivs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
for(var divIndex = 0; divIndex < nestedDivs.length; divIndex++)
{
    nestedDivs[divIndex].style.backgroundColor = 'red';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var parent = document.getElementById("room");
var divs = parent.getElementsByTagName('div');
for (i=0; i<divs.length; i++)
{
    divs[i].className="grass";
};
```